# How do I handle files stored as blob from react-dropzone

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework, axios, react-dropzone

When I add files to the file field using react-dropzone and pass it to a remote Django backend, it passes the values:

```
{u'preview': u'blob:http://127.0.0.1:8080/17c3c181-e361-44f1-8ee8
-6476847aeffb'}
```

.  How do I handle that as a file for uploading to S3 using a Django Rest API backend?